# UDP Peer to Peer Chat Server using Mobile Reliable UDP (MR-UDP)

Tags: java, networking, mobile, udp

I am attempting to use MR-UDP (http://lac-rio.com/mr-udp/#dl) to make a simple peer to peer based chat application. I have two major classes so far, Multiplexer which reads and writes IO events and fires listeners when messages arrive or states change. I have written it in this way to integrate easily into a UI. The Console class is just a simple temporary main class to test sending a message. The peers find each other and connect fine, however it seems that somewhere my protocol is being corrupted.

My magic ids are not failing, however my Peer.read/writeString methods seems to be getting corrupted.. I send packet id one but it receives id 16. I can't seem to see the error.

It sends a message packet. When the other end receives the packet, is opcode and size has been corrupted! To be more specific, the packets being received in the parse() method are somehow corrupt.

The expected behavior would be for the clients to connect (which they do) and then exchange the message "Hi!" with each other, once connected.

Main class:

```
package com;

import com.net.Multiplexer;
import com.net.Multiplexer.Peer;
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * @author Colby
 */
public class Console implements Multiplexer.MultiplexListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Console c = new Console();

        c.m = new Multiplexer(c, 5555);
        c.m.start();
        c.m.connect("Colby", InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }

    private Peer lastPeer;
    private Multiplexer m;

    @Override
    public void onPing(Multiplexer.Peer p) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect(Peer p) {
        System.out.println("[" + p.user() + "]: Connected!");
        lastPeer = p;
        m.send("Hi!", p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(Multiplexer.Peer p) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Multiplexer.Peer p, String message) {
        System.out.println("[" + p.user() + "]: " + message);
    }
}
```

Multiplexer:
    package com.net;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import net.rudp.ReliableServerSocket;
import net.rudp.ReliableSocket;
import net.rudp.ReliableSocketOutputStream;

/**
 * Handles sending/receiving packets on a single port
 *
 * @author Colby
 */
public class Multiplexer {

    private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public Multiplexer(MultiplexListener listener, int port) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.port = port;
    }

    private final LinkedList<Peer> peers;
    private final MultiplexListener listener;
    private final PacketDirector packets;

    {
        packets = new PacketDirector();
        peers = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    private final int port;
    private boolean running;
    private ReliableServerSocket ssock;

    public void connect(String user, InetAddress addr) {

        pool.submit(() -> {

            try {
                ReliableSocket s = new ReliableSocket(addr.getHostAddress(), port);
                Peer p = new Peer(s, true);
                p.user = user;
                pool.submit(p);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        pool.submit(new Server());
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        ssock.close();
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    public void send(String message, Peer p) {
        pool.submit(() -> {
            try {
                p.send(message);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public Peer getPeer(String user) {
        for (Peer p : peers) {
            if (p.user.equals(user)) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class Server implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ssock = new ReliableServerSocket(port);
                do {
                    Peer peer = new Peer(ssock.accept());
                    pool.submit(peer);

                } while (running);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Peer implements Runnable {

        private Peer(Socket sock, boolean client) throws IOException {
            this.sock = sock;

            auth = client ? new ClientPeerAuthenticator() : new PeerAuthenticator();

            in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            buffer = new DataOutputStream((ReliableSocketOutputStream) sock.getOutputStream());
        }

        private Peer(Socket sock) throws IOException {
            this(sock, false);
        }
        private final long uid;
        private int version;
        private String user;

        {
            uid = (long) (Long.MAX_VALUE * Math.random() * (Math.random() > 0.5D ? 1 : -1));
        }
        private final Socket sock;
        private final DataInputStream in;
        private final DataOutputStream buffer;
        private final PeerAuthenticator auth;

        public String user() {
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            pool.submit(() -> {

                try {
                    try {
                        do {
                            parse();
                            Thread.sleep(500);

                        } while (running);

                    } finally {
                        disconnect();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            try {
                if (auth()) {
                    listener.onConnect(this);
                    do {
                        synchronized (Multiplexer.this) {
                            try {
                                Multiplexer.this.wait();

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                            buffer.flush();
                            System.out.println("FLUSH0");
                        }

                    } while (running);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void flush() throws IOException {
            synchronized (Multiplexer.this) {
                Multiplexer.this.notify();
            }
        }

        private boolean auth() throws IOException {
            return auth.auth(this);
        }

        private void disconnect() throws IOException {
            try {
                buffer.close();
                in.close();
                sock.close();
                flush();

            } finally {
                listener.onDisconnect(this);
            }
        }

        private int opcode = -1, length = -1;

        private boolean parse() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("0");
            if (opcode == -1) {
                if (in.available() < 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                opcode = in.readByte();
            }
            System.out.println("1 " + opcode);
            if (length == -1) {
                if (in.available() < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
                length = in.readShort();
            }
            System.out.println("3 " + length);
            if (in.available() < length) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("4");

            System.out.println("HANDLE0");

            byte[] packetData = new byte[length];
            in.readFully(packetData);

            DataInputStream pin = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packetData));
            packets.handlePacket(opcode, length, pin, this);

            opcode = length = -1;
            return in.available() > 0;
        }

        public void send(String message) throws IOException {
            writeString(message);
            flush();
        }

        private void writeString(String message) throws IOException {
            byte[] data = message.getBytes();
            buffer.writeByte(1);
            buffer.writeShort(data.length);
            buffer.write(data);
        }

        private String readString() throws IOException {
            int length = in.readByte();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            in.readFully(data);

            return new String(data);
        }
    }

    private class PeerAuthenticator {

        public boolean auth(Peer p) throws IOException {
            int magic = p.in.readUnsignedByte();
            if (magic != 255) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid magic: " + magic);
            }

            p.version = p.in.readUnsignedShort();
            p.user = p.readString();

            System.out.println("read nick " + p.user);

            p.buffer.writeByte(255);
            p.buffer.writeLong(p.uid);
            p.buffer.flush();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class ClientPeerAuthenticator extends PeerAuthenticator {

        @Override
        public boolean auth(Peer p) throws IOException {
            p.buffer.writeByte(255);
            p.buffer.writeShort(10000);
            p.writeString("Colby");
            p.buffer.flush();

            if(p.in.readUnsignedByte() != 255) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid magic");
            }
            p.in.readLong();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class PacketDirector {

        private final PacketHandler[] handlers = {
            new PingHandler(),//0
            new TextHandler()//1
        };

        private void handlePacket(int opcode, int length, DataInputStream in, Peer p) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Opcode " + opcode + " Size:" + length);
            handlers[opcode].handlePacket(opcode, length, in, p);
        }
    }

    private interface PacketHandler {

        void handlePacket(int opcode, int length, DataInputStream in, Peer p) throws IOException;
    }

    private class PingHandler implements PacketHandler {

        @Override
        public void handlePacket(int opcode, int length, DataInputStream in, Peer p) throws IOException {
            listener.onPing(p);
        }
    }

    private class TextHandler implements PacketHandler {

        @Override
        public void handlePacket(int opcode, int length, DataInputStream in, Peer p) throws IOException {
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            in.readFully(data);
            listener.onMessage(p, new String(data));
        }
    }

    public interface MultiplexListener {

        void onPing(Peer p);

        void onConnect(Peer p);

        void onDisconnect(Peer p);

        void onMessage(Peer p, String message);
    }
}
```

Also if there is some library to make this easier please suggest! I must be able to send raw binary data using UDP!

Comment: I like the Peer to *Beer* concept :-) Seriously could you emphasize the problem you get, what you expected and what is wrong. It seem you get a wrong ID, but could you rewrite so it is more understandable?

Comment: @mins When I call m.send("Hi!", p); it sends a message packet. When the other end receives the packet, is opcode and size has been corrupted!

Comment: To be more specific, the packets being received in the parse() method are somehow corrupt.

Comment: Please include the explanations in these two comments into your question.